# Output pointer returns (null) instead of char value

Tags: arrays, c, loops, struct, c-strings

Program below have to return pointer to an array of names taken from names[] if *pMonthToStudy parameter of Exam function equals birth month of coressponding person (birthDates[] order corresponds to names[] order). In case of June, function should return "John, James, Richard". The output must have exactly the same view as my example.

**Do I allocate memory correct?
If yes, how to assign those values to returning pointer and output it correctly in main (if my output method is incorrect)?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int day;
    char month[4];
    int year;
} DATE;

DATE birthDates[] = {{2, "Jun", 2000}, {27, "Jul", 2001}, {12, "Jun", 1999},
                     {15, "Sep", 1998}, {16, "Jun", 2000}};

char names[] = {"John, Mary, James, Elizabeth, Richard"};

char *Exam(char *pNames, DATE *pBirthDates, const char *pMonthToStudy){
    //Check if input ptr are zero or point to empty strings
    if(!pNames || !*pNames || !pBirthDates)
        return 0;
    char *pOutput = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*pNames));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if(strcmp(pMonthToStudy, &birthDates->month[i]) == 0){
            strcpy(pOutput, &pNames[i]);
        } else
            return 0;
    }
    return pOutput;
}
int main() {
    char *pResult = Exam(names, birthDates, "Jun");
    printf("%s", pResult);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *pOutput = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*pNames));` allocates 1 byte. When you pass an array to a function, you need to pass it's length as well in a separate argument.

Comment: The expression `*pNames` is the same as `pNames[0]`. And `pNames[0]` is a single `char`. So `sizeof(*pNames)` is the size of a single `char` which will always be `1`. So you only allocate one byte for your string `pOutput`. The only null-terminated string it can hold is an empty string `""`.

Comment: Not sure that `char names[] = {"John, Mary, James, Elizabeth, Richard"};` does what you think it does.

Comment: `&birthDates->month[i]` should be `birthDates[i].month`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int day;
    char month[4];
    int year;
} DATE;

DATE birthDates[] = { {2, "Jun", 2000}, {27, "Jul", 2001}, {12, "Jun", 1999},
                     {15, "Sep", 1998}, {16, "Jun", 2000} };

const char *names[] = { "John", "Mary", "James", "Elizabeth", "Richard" };

char *Exam(const char **pNames, DATE *pBirthDates, const char *pMonthToStudy) {
    if (!pNames || !*pNames || !pBirthDates)
        return 0;
    char *pOutput = NULL;
    const char * prefix = ", ";
    int nSize = 0;
    int nCount = 0;
    int *arrIndexes = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strcmp(pMonthToStudy, birthDates[i].month) == 0) {
            nSize += strlen(pNames[i]);

            arrIndexes[nCount] = i;

            nCount++;
        }
    }

    const int mallocSize = (nSize + (nCount - 1) * sizeof(prefix)) * sizeof(char) + 1;
    pOutput = (char*)(malloc(mallocSize));

    memset(pOutput, 0, mallocSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++) {
        strcat_s(pOutput, mallocSize, pNames[arrIndexes[i]]);

        if (i != nCount - 1) {
            strcat_s(pOutput, mallocSize, prefix);
        }
    }

    return pOutput;
}
int main() {
    char *pResult = Exam(names, birthDates, "Jun");
    printf("%s", pResult);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For starters this declaration

```
char names[] = {"John, Mary, James, Elizabeth, Richard"};
```

declares a character array with one element that contains the string literal

```
"John, Mary, James, Elizabeth, Richard"
```

As a result in this declaration

```
char *pOutput = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*pNames));
```

there is allocated only one character.

It seems you mean an array of 5 elements of pointers to string literals

```
char * names[] = { "John", "Mary", "James", "Elizabeth", "Richard"};
```

Nevertheless in this declaration with a wrong initialization

```
char *pOutput = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*pNames));
```

you need to allocate a character array that can be able to store a corresponding string literal in the array names.

This allocation must be done after the for loop if the target record is found. Otherwise the function will have a memory leak.

The for loop is incorrect

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    if(strcmp(pMonthToStudy, &birthDates->month[i]) == 0){
        strcpy(pOutput, &pNames[i]);
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

It can return 0 in the first iteration of the loop or 0 even when the target record will be found because you do not interrupt the loop in this case. And moreover you are using incorrect expressions in the functions `strcmp` and `strcpy`.

Instead write

```
char *pOutput = NULL;

int i = 0;

while ( i < 5 && strcmp( pMonthToStudy, birthDates[i].month ) != 0 ) ++i;


if ( i != 5 )
{
    pOutput = malloc( strlen( pNames[i] ) + 1 );
    if ( pOutput != NULL ) strcpy( pOutput, pNames[i] );
}

return pOutput;
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to use the magic number 5 within the function. You should pass the number of elements in the referenced arrays through a function parameter.